# Увеличение времени выполнения методов в определенном классе

Tags: php

В определенном классе нужно увеличить время выполнения методов. Будет ли правильно прописать функцию set_time_limit() вот так?

```
<?php

set_time_limit(3600);
class AjaxController extends controller {
   // ...
}
```

Будет ли это работать правильно для методов класса, когда я буду создавать новый объект класса AjaxController?

```
$aj = new AjaxController();
```

Comment: Для задержки выполнения нужно использовать [sleep](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php).

Comment: Кажется вы занимаетесь ерундой пытаясь синхронизировать какие то процессы. Я думаю, вы выбрали неверное решение если только не пишите код для закрытия гермозатворов в метро после объявления тревоги.

Comment: Ответ на поставленный вопрос - нет, не будет